Работа 3д графики
Я решил создать с нуля 3д графику на С++, без дополнительных программ и библиотек по типу opengl и sfml, я могу сделать только как в первых частях вульфштейн и дум, но это не 3д, а 2д. Нигде в интернете не могу найти описание того как она работает

Как без дополнительных программ и библиотек нарисовать точку на экране?

В первых частях вульфштейн и дум вполне себе 3d, просто на современных на тот момент технологиях, и рендерилось на CPU, а не на GPU, как сейчас. Если хорошо поискать, можно найти исходники Wolfenstein3D.

"Нигде в интернете не могу найти описание того как она работает" - не верю, в интернете помимо собственно исходного кода упомянутых игр, еще и детальные разборы имются использованных техник

Для начала напиши шейдер.

Почитайте хотя бы про ray tracing и всё такое.
